# How to convert datetime stored in MySQL, to a different format using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have date stored in MySQL DB using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default, so that when a new data is inserted the date and time is stored automatically. And, I want to retrieve this data and display in my `PHP`. The retrived data looks like this `2019-03-17 15:02:36` .

Now I need to change it to `March 17 2019` in my output.

I tried using `date_format()` but it is not displaying any output. It just returns blank data.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: Hint: Try it in your statement like `DATE_FORMAT (erstelltam, \"%dth %b %Y at %H:%i:%S Uhr\") AS erstelltam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) functions of PHP to the rescue.

```
$sqldate = '2019-03-17 15:02:36';
$sqldate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d G:i:s',$sqldate);
echo $sqldate->format('F d Y');
```

Produces:

> March 17 2019

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple use below code

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(YOURDATECOLUMN,'%d/%m/%Y') AS niceDate 
FROM table 
ORDER BY YOURDATECOLUMN DESC
```

Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/82244